# How many coins to give for change

Tags: c++

I am new to c++. The problem consists in minimizing the number of coins required to give the exact change I have 25 10 5 and 1 cent coins.

For example if a customer is owed $3.20 the number of coins to give would be 14 (12 of 25 and 2 of 10).

My problem:
A number like 4.20 says you need 22 coins instead of 18. I know the problem is generated when it multiplies change by 100. I get 419 instead of 420.

Here is my code.

```
int coins = change * 100;   
//How many 25 cent coins you need
if (coins >= 25)
{
    quarter = coins / 25;
    coins = coins % 25;        
}

//How many 10 cent coins you need
if (coins >= 10)
{
    dimes = coins / 10;
    coins = coins % 10;
}

//How many 5 cent coins you need
if (coins >= 5)
{
    nickels = coins / 5;
    coins = coins % 5;  
}
//How many 1 cent coins you need
if (coins >= 1)
{
    pennies = coins / 1;
    coins = coins % 1;   
}

NumCoins = quarter + dimes + nickels + pennies;

printf("%d \n", NumCoins);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Caught up by rounding or (unwanted) integer division problems maybe?

Comment: what's the type of `change`? And why do you even use `printf` in `C++`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Does sound like a rounding issue, I just tried this in c# with float as the change variable, and I get 419.

Comment: change is a float. I use printf because its from a library I was giving to do my homework with, it would be like doing cout<<.

Comment: @user3149979 when the user inputs the change, do you get it as a char array or float or what? If it is a char array then it is simple as removing the '.' character and convert that to int, instead of change * 100.

Comment: @user3149979 Sorry you're missing to specify all of the other variable types accordingly! **Edit your post** to have an [SCCEE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, if you want to get reasonable answers here!

Comment: You could see what other people have done with this assignment by searching StackOverflow for "c++ calculate change coin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of the problem my suggestion on how to do this is essentially having two variables. `change` (This is the change you have in cents.) as well as `coins` (This is the total number of coins you need to make change.)

Then once you have the change, you keep subtracting the quarters (that is `25`), from the `change` variable until it is less than `25`, then you move onto dimes, nickels and finally pennies. At the same time you decrement the `change` variable, you increment the `coins` in order to keep track of the minimum number of coins you need. This should be much cleaner and simpler than keeping track of all these other variables.

Some pseudocode could look like this:

```
declare variables
do loop of change > 25
    change  = change - 25
    coins = coins + 1
do loop of change > 10
    ...
(keep doing this for dimes, nickels and pennies)
    ...
display number of coins needed.
```

Comment: Having multiple variables would be helpful if he needs to output what the exact coins were, either way this answer is very helpful. We still however need to explain to OP why he is getting 419 when multiplying the change by 100 instead of 420 (rounding issue it seems).

Comment: @JohnOdom, thank you. This is but a mere suggestion since reading over  his questions, it doesn't seem like he needs to.

Comment: @Link Really? Pseudo code, while the OP's asking for some concrete [tag:c++] code??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I left it in pseudocode because it is merely a suggestion on how to approach the problem another way. It's easy enough to implement anyways.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int amount = 420;
  int coins[] = { 25, 10, 5, 1 };

  int ncoins = 0;
  for( int i=0 ; i<sizeof(coins)/sizeof(int) ; ++i )
  {
    ncoins += amount / coins[i];
    amount %= coins[i];
  }
  cout << "You need " << ncoins << " coin(s)." << endl;
}
```

> You need 18 coin(s).

It is easy to track which specific coins are needed in the for loop. I assume the reader can adjust the code as needed to suit their purposes.

Comment: +1 for not disclosing **all** of the final solution in code!